# Reverse engineering, transistor function in this subsystem

Tags: transistors, reverse-engineering

Based on a previous question: [What went wrong in my reverse engineering?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681029/what-went-wrong-in-my-reverse-engineering/681032?noredirect=1#comment1813410_681032)

I reverse engineered a toaster. I can isolate a subsystem of the schematics as follows:

[image]

VDD is around 20V DC over VSS. We compute the base current at around 4mA.
Then the transistor is saturated and the led current is something like 4mA too.

Is my computation correct? Isn't it too low for a LED to light? Isn't it too high for a base current?

What would be the purpose of the transistor here ? It seems that the current that goes through the LED is similar  to the current that goes out of the 4066.

The full schematics is as follows :
[image]
[image]

Comment: An LED lights visibly at ~nA -- depending on how dark the ambient is, and how well adjusted your eyes are. A superbright at rated current might be painful to look at.  Also, surely you mean 13mA Ic?

Comment: Did you mean 4mA base current instead of collector current?

Comment: Where do the wires go that leave the schematic to the top and the right?

Comment: To logical entries of the 4066 pin 6 and 12. The schematics below has two wires coming in, it's the same wire, but I admit it's messy.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, 4mA is not too low for an LED. Many are too bright even at 1mA.
2. No, 4mA is not too high for base current. A generic BC547 can be driven with 5mA to allow 100mA collector current if you need it. And since you took this circuit out of context, we don't know what other loads your circuit really has in addition to the LED.

Comment: Indeed it may depends on what is next, but i suggest it doesn't matter. I updated to add full schematics.